# Sync 2 radio button from differend forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Can JQuery Sync one radio button to another when first input is modified?

For example:

```
<input id="form1" type="radio" name="option-1" value="Mastercard"> 
If I check something here<br>


<input id="form2" type="radio" name="contact[option-1]" value="Mastercard"> 
It will be checked here<br>
```

Can JQuery Do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#form1").click(function(){
    $("#form2").attr("checked",$(this).is(':checked')); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xw6dtnxL/)**